# An exception occurred in driver: could not find driver (Symfony)

Tags: php, symfony, pdo, yaml, composer-php

I have a problem.
I did a very simple code just for trying Symfony and it dont works.
I know there are so many similar posts but i didnt found my same case.
This is the php:

```
<?php
namespace App\Controller;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
class DavidPalacin
{
    public function Gimenez()
    {
        return new Response('Funciona');
    }
}
```

And this is the routes.yaml:

```
index:
  path: /
  controller: App\Controller\DavidPalacinController::Gimenez
```

So, as u see, is very simple, but when i execute thats what are happening me:
[first error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/98vY1.png)

And these are all the errors in general that appears:
[All errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hh8UO.png)

I can read something about "pdo" but i dont know what it means...

By the way. If it can help this is my "php -m":[php -m](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S1A35.png)
And my php version is 8.0.3

Comment: Do you have a Postgres server and is your PHP configured with Postgres support?

Comment: Nope, can it be the fail? If it is how can i have what u are saying?